# Typo3 form 9.5.11 how to add my own class to element?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I am using form (9.5.11) to make a relatively simple form, just needs a fieldset to be in the HTML structure with a custom class on it with value: col-sm-6 for Bootstrap.

This is a piece of the .yaml:

```
renderables:
  -
    type: Fieldset
    identifier: fieldset-1
    label: ''
    renderables:
      -
        defaultValue: ''
        type: Text
        identifier: text-1
        label: ''
        properties:
          fluidAdditionalAttributes:
            placeholder: 'First Name'
            required: required
```

How can i possibly add a class to the fieldset?

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 4):

The answer is:

```
properties:
  elementClassAttribute: 'col-sm-6'
```

On the fieldset:

```
renderables:
  -
    type: Fieldset
    identifier: fieldset-1
    label: ''
    properties:
      elementClassAttribute: 'col-sm-6'
    renderables:
      -
        defaultValue: ''
        type: Text
        identifier: text-1
        label: ''
        properties:
          fluidAdditionalAttributes:
            placeholder: 'First Name'
            required: required
```